# Follow Solver - To follow on Z Axis Only

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I am working on a project which shows navigation from one point to another in Hololens. I am trying to create this application via MRTK2.

I have created a navigator Arrow and I want it to follow the user Head only on Z- Axis. It should Restrict any movement on the X and Y axis.
For this, I have attached Follow Solver to Object and have Added tracked Target type to Head.
Also, I have attached Move Axis COnstraint Script to restrict movement on the X and Y axis.
[image: Scene Image]

But When I play scenes, Object position and rotation values are changed. Something like below.
[image: Play Mode]

It works from the script when I calculate the camera position and Update the arrow position.

```
straightarrow.transform.position = new Vector3(straightarrowpos.x, straightarrowpos.y, camposition.z + 2.623f);
```

Is there any way this can be handled via Solvers instead of updating the position via script?

Mayank Pande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints and **Constraint manager** provided by MRTK are currently only applicable to **Bounds control** and **Object manipulator**, please refer to [Constraint manager - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/constraint-manager?view=mrtkunity-2022-05). Existing solvers cannot meet your needs, but you can create a new solver, please refer to [Solver overview - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/solvers/solver?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#how-to-create-a-new-solver).